# Profile guided optimization

Tags: optimization, compiler-optimization, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I am getting link time error __PogoRuntimeVector when I use /GL and /LTCG:PGI to instrument a DLL. Since nm/dumpbin cannot be used, I could not figure out what causes this error. Can someone throw pointer to it?

-Kartlee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We finally found the solution. Linking with pgort.lib or pgobootrun.lib solve the issue.

See this article for reference - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/11/12/pogo.aspx

-Karthik